# How to rename / move a folder in react native fs?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, filesystems, react-native-fs

I am having trouble renaming and moving folders cause react native fs has only moveFile option that performs on files only and not folders.Doing it recursive is also messy and it is hard to execute lines after performing rename or move option due to synchronous execution.I have attached the code for move below with the bug.Kindly help me figure this out.

```
moveAll = (path, outputPath) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
// is a folder
if (path.split(".").length == 1) {
  // CHeck if folder already exists
  RNFS.exists(outputPath)
    .then((exists) => {
      if (exists) {
        // Delete the folder if exists
        RNFS.unlink(outputPath)
          .then(() => {

          })
          // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      }
      // MAKE FRESH FOLDER
      RNFS.mkdir(outputPath);
      resolve(RNFS.readDir(path)
        .then((result) => {
          result.map(
            (item) =>
              new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(this.moveAll(item.path, outputPath + "/" + item.name));
              })
          )
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("ERROR", e)
        })
      )
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })

} else {
  RNFS.moveFile(path, outputPath)
    .then(() => {
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}
})
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help I figured the answer with your solutions

```
moveAll = async (path, outputPath) => {
    // is a folder
    if (path.split(".").length == 1) {
      // CHeck if folder already exists
      var exists = await RNFS.exists(outputPath);
      if (exists) {
        await RNFS.unlink(outputPath);
        await RNFS.mkdir(outputPath);
      }
      // MAKE FRESH FOLDER
      var result = await RNFS.readDir(path);
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].isDirectory()) {
          await RNFS.mkdir(outputPath + "/" + result[i].name);
        }
        var val = await this.moveAll(result[i].path, outputPath + "/" + result[i].name);
      }
      await RNFS.unlink(path);
      return 1;
    } else {
      await RNFS.moveFile(path, outputPath);
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: In my practice, need remove this code line `var exists = await RNFS.exists(outputPath)`, and replace `if (exists) {...}` with just one line code `await RNFS.mkdir(outputPath);`

Answer (score 1):

you can call `this.moveDirectorySafely("source","destination");` to Recursive move/rename

make sure you have Allowed storage permissions

if you got any error then you can call `RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath).then` to check if this folder exists or not

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

export default class index extends Component {
  firstSource = '';
  componentDidMount() {
    this.moveDirectorySafely('source', 'destination'); //you can call this function
  }

  moveDirectorySafely = (src, dst) => {
    RNFS.exists(dst).then((dirExists) => {
      if (dirExists) {
        RNFS.unlink(dst).then(() => {
          this.moveDirectory(src, dst);
        });
      } else {
        this.moveDirectory(src, dst);
      }
    });
  };

  moveDirectory = (src, dst, root = true) =>
    new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (root) {
        src = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/' + src;
        dst = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/' + dst;
        this.firstSource = src;
      }
      RNFS.mkdir(dst)
        .then(() => {
          RNFS.readDir(src)
            .then(async (files) => {
              for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                const name = files[i].name;
                const filepath = src + '/' + name;
                const destpath = src.replace(src, dst);
                const destfile = destpath + '/' + name;

                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                  RNFS.mkdir(destfile)
                    .then(async () => {
                      await this.moveDirectory(filepath, destfile, false);
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                      reject(e);
                    });
                } else {
                  await RNFS.copyFile(filepath, destfile);
                }
                if (i === files.length - 1) {
                  RNFS.unlink(this.firstSource)
                    .then(() => {
                      resolve();
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                      reject(e);
                    });
                }
              }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              reject(err);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  render() {
    return <View></View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for copying folders right...In case of move, we have to delete the existing folder and paste it into destination.I am having trouble in deleting the existing folder.

Comment: @VishalTennyson I have updated my answer now you can check

Comment: Now it keeps on throwing error -  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Object {}

Comment: Yes.Now the error is [Error: Folder does not exist] and for your information my source and destination are already absolute path including from root so I commented the two lines inside if(root) and run it

Comment: Doesn't work as well...[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'path.startsWith')] is the error now

Comment: My linux desktop has little issues connecting to servers like anydesk..So it won't be of any use I guess

Comment: Nah bro...Some problem with wayland...I just have trouble understanding recursion in javascript...Cause every recursion occurs in parallel instead of waiting for inner recursion to finish...Thus the main directory calls all the recursion and performs delete folder at that moment itself causing inner recursion to fail

Comment: I resolved it thanks...You can check it if you want

Comment: @VishalTennyson i want to know about bounty

Comment: I gave it...Thanks for the help mate...Please stay in touch